# Swift: Load custom UIView from xib programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initialization

This should be relatively simple in Objective-C, but I'm running into problems trying to implement it in Swift.

I have a `xib` and two IBOutlets to a custom UIView. But when I initialize the view I get an error saying that my IBOutlets are nil.

Here's my CustomView:

```
import UIKit

class MessageView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderImageView: UIImageView!

    override convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    convenience init(message: String, gender: Gender) {
        self.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40))

        messageLabel.text = message
        genderImageView.image = UIImage(named: "male")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I'm calling the convenience initializer from my view controller, and it fails on the `messageLabel.text = message` line saying that `messageLabel` is `nil`.

I thought `self.init(frame:)` would initialize my xib? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How are you initialising it? You need to be instantiating the nib file and loading the view from there. View.init will not use the nib. Only the code.

Comment: Where should I initialize it?

Comment: Search for "load view from nib" there are loads of qs already for this.

Comment: Right, so `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MessageView", owner: self, options: nil)`. But where do I put it?

Comment: You should put the code the place where you want to create instance of the MessageView.