# Swift: Append Custom UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiview

This is a *near* duplicate of this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325371/swift-load-custom-uiview-from-xib-programmatically), however I'm running into some issues that it makes it appear like I'm not doing it correctly. For reference, I followed this [excellent tutorial on creating re-usable views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk) from a custom class and xib file (it's only a few minutes :) and I have no problems at all dragging that into another view onto my storyboard (as demonstrated at the end of the video)

Nevertheless for my case — I'm trying to call my custom class programmatically, and add it as a subview to one of my `ScrollView` instances.

```
class MainController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        first.directionalLockEnabled = true
        first.pagingEnabled = true
        var item = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 200))
        self.scrollView.addSubview(item)
    }

}
```

My Custom view looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dressTitle: UILabel!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.view.frame = bounds
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
}
```

There is an associated `.xib` file with it too that has the label and image.

So my question is, my view never appears in my ScrollView. I've double checked the constraints on my scroll view... I can even append simple `UIView`'s with obvious visible dimensions `CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)`... and nothing ever gives. What am I missing?

Comment: can you print more information on viewDidAppear??
such as, self.view.frame and self.scrollView.frame also the self.scrollView.subViews.count

Comment: `customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero(top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 50)` try like this

Comment: Yeah, I tried those just in case too :). My main `self.view.frame` is `(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)` and the `self.scrollView.frame` is `(0.0, 11.0, 320.0, 200.0)`

Comment: @ded check this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk

Comment: @AshishKakkad If you wouldn't mind, please re-read my question carefully — I already referenced that **exact video** in the original question as the tutorial that I followed.

Comment: You read tutorials about UIView, what about tutorials about UIScrollView ? You don't use constraints or contentSize, so I guess there is a problem with your scrollView. Try http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Comment: Hey all, thanks for chiming in to help so quickly. I sorted it out and posted an answer. Thanks for your time - I definitely appreciate it!

Comment: @ded Oh Ok, I does not seen the question perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some messing around I accidentally got it to work by duplicating the `loadFromNib` method to a second initializer in the `CustomView.swift` file. As seen in the video tutorial posted in the original question it shows just one of the initializers.... but in my case I had to add extra code to the `init(frame)`. Eg:

```
// once with a NSCoder
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Item", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.view.frame = bounds
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}

// for this to work programmatically I had to do the same...
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Item", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.view.frame = bounds
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}
```